# Get CPU usage for single process

Tags: process, freebsd, cpu

I've got a problem getting a real-time CPU usage of a single process (by its PID). I'd like to setup a watchdog for the CPU usage of a process because it's suddenly reaching 100% of the CPU usage sometimes.

**What I have tried**:

`top -p $PID`, `top -pid $PID` - seems like those two are not working on FreeBSD

`ps h -p $PID -o %cpu` - works, but returned CPU usage percentage is always `0`.

The question is - how can I get a real time CPU usage for a single process by its PID **on FreeBSD**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have access to a BSD machine to check but your `ps` command should work as advertised. In any case, as a dirty hack, you could always just parse the output of the full `ps` (where `NNN` is the PID you are after):

```
ps aux | awk  -v OFS="\t" '$2=="NNN"'
```

Or, to keep the output format identical to that of `ps`:

```
ps aux | grep -i '^[a-z ]*NNN '
```

You may have to tweak the `ps` options a bit since they're different in BSD. Just use whichever combination prints all processes.